# Changing shape of multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `B` with shape `(1,9,1)`. Is it possible to convert into a new array `B1` with shape `(1,3,3)`? The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

B=np.array([[[0.67873113],
              [1.24442563],
              [0.02109   ],
              [0.76788408],
              [2.00615422],
              [3.07375839],
              [1.037729  ],
              [5.03294753],
              [0.0105    ]]])
print("B shape =",B.shape)
```

The desired output is

```
B1=np.array([[[0.67873113,1.24442563,0.02109   ],
             [0.76788408,2.00615422,3.07375839],
             [1.037729,5.03294753,0.0105    ]]])

B1 shape = (1, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Did you try `B.reshape(1, 3, 3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reshape it. See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
B.reshape((1,3,3))

>>> array([[[0.67873113, 1.24442563, 0.02109   ],
        [0.76788408, 2.00615422, 3.07375839],
        [1.037729  , 5.03294753, 0.0105    ]]])
```